# Formula to Move the object in Circular Path

Tags: analytic-geometry, circles

I want to move one object (dot) in circular path.

By using x and y position of that object.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

x and y should satisfy $x^2+y^2=r^2$, where r is radius of the circle.

**Edit:**

How to move the point in circular path by adding value of x and y? I want to create a circular path by looping the formula. –  Ganapathy

Ans: 
let

> x=rcos(t), y=rsin(t)

loop over t

Comment: How to move the point in circular path by adding value of x and y? i want to create a circular path by looping the formula.

Comment: let x=r*cos(t), y=r*sin(t), loop over t

Comment: this works exactly dude Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to choose from, but a nice one that doesn't require per-step trig functions (so can be calculated by a computer very quickly) is the [midpoint circle algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm).

Otherwise, you can use $x=\cos(\theta)*\text{radius}$, $y=\sin(\theta)*\text{radius}$ for $0 < \theta < 360^\circ$.

Answer (score 1):

Is this part of a piece of software? Clarification on what you need would be very helpful.

If the object each frame has a velocity vector which it follows, just rotate the velocity vector through some fixed angle each frame. The easiest way would be to build a rotation matrix and multiply by the matrix. In a very naive implementation, you would then add the velocity to the position vector each frame. In most applications, this is insufficient, and it is preferable to use [Verlet integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verlet_integration), mainly in the presence of acceleration.

Or you can parameterize the points on the circle as a function of time using the relations $x = c_x + r\cos(t), y = c_y + r\sin(t)$ for $(c_x,c_y)$ the circle's center, $r$ its radius, and $t$ the time.